# Interviewer's Room

Tags: code-golf, sorting

> You are *James* and **four** of your friends (*Bjarne*, *Eich*, *Rossum*, *Ada*) are called for an interview. There are **n** interviewers, and they can *each serve one* person at a time, **alphabetically**. Each round of interview takes **20** min.

Let's take **n = 2**,

> So, the first round started with *Ada* and *Bjarne*, takes 20 min (they're handled simultaneously). Then, interviewers call persons for next round, who are *Eich* and ***James***, they took another 20 min.

Hence, finally you're out after 40 min.

---

## Challenge

Given an array as input like `["yourName", [an, Array, Of, Friends], numberOfInterviewers]`, your task is to output the time it'll take for you to complete the interview, in minutes.

<sup>Feel free to take three arguments as input, instead of the array.</sup>

#### Sample I/O:

(`In = Out` format)

```
[ "James", ["Bjarne", "Eich"   , "Rossum", "Ada"  ], 2  ]   =   40
[ "Stark", ["Steve" , "Tchalla", "Banner", "Scott"], 3  ]   =   20
[ "spam" , ["bar"   , "eggs"   , "foo"   , "lorem"], 1  ]   =   100
[ "Oggy" , ["Jack"  , "DeeDee" , "Marky" , "Bob"  ], 10 ]   =   20
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes will win!

Comment: Why can't you just do `Alice, Bob, Carol, Dave, Eve`? It makes the challenge significantly easier to understand.

Comment: @petStorm, I'd like to make it a bit interesting.

Comment: Yes @DLosc, it is always exactly four friends. However, the golfing is always allowed to be _creative_, so anyone can _optionally_ add custom test cases, if they wish (to be mentioned in their answer).

Comment: Can we take all 5 names as a single array with "ours" consistently at the same index? Are we guaranteed that all 5 names will be different?

Comment: No @Shaggy, it's not possible now. Further, all 5 names are unique, to make the challenge legal. Also, number of interviewers could not be zero.

Comment: Bad? Okay, let me repair that example, just a sec. Also, all the names are one-word and in capitalized form. @user, edited the example.

Comment: @RahulVerma Thank you very much! That's not exactly what I meant - I was fine with the challenge being harder, but hopefully this will make it easier for people to focus on the core of the problem

Comment: Are the names guaranteed to only contain letters?

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @JonathanAllan!*

```python
lambda s,l,n:~sum(x<s for x in l)/n*-20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY89T8MwEIb3/oqTFxJkShqYKjJQYKmEkChby@AmlzTUX7Ldql346@GcpCqWP87v3fv4bM9hZ3Te1cWmk0JtKwGeS67nv/6gktOTh9o4OEGrQab3@vYuz7pWWeMC@LOfxKRsNcY83ac@VK2eTwCSnpJywJPFMmAFBShhEzwKyXvL1FvZhoQVLE3J4NAfZKCqerSSZl2rw5jh41kUF2K3BrYUCj3jsGaLH@E0Usje2nLHgAbFn8bTP6L6XAkSvznktFOyoPWYTYixCsLte8Yq4BFZ9H3dvOyElCI6F0JrdDFalSYERoyHKyPvGd4KFY1rthWODW9j0/hLH7UxoyqNQxUZsytjlvWQj6Y5D5ClKPesL39FpDnE79RnX8AWZjt8Zpb9a@QP)

Comment: `lambda s,l,n:~sum(x<s for x in l)/n*-20` saves one :)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>44</s>  40 bytes

```javascript
(s,a,n)=>-~(a.map(S=>k+=s>S,k=0),k/n)*20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc89T8MwEAbgnV9h3UIMbvMBayIRYKmEkAhbxXBNL26bxI5sU4mFvx7sJF2o5eHVyX703gnPaGtzHNxK6T2NTT5GVqBQPC9WvxGuexyiKi/a@9wWlWjzhIs2VvwuS8ZaK6s7WndaRk0EG@zJgmBbKE9oFPkIr8f6AMwfnz@0td99mD7t0Q@/BMsY5yyO2WNy8w@rHJp2wipHZ4IAfN4@H7DrMBAlKkUmpKrWzoHHHhYsu8LsgH0QtrBDA3MbktJemjVaL9NOG@oDli5Ymlxp71L@zNoG6xamfy9E/s75zTefHkCpd/OeaXKpNv4B)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>50</s> <s>49</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Robin Ryder*

```r
function(y,f,n)sum(f<y,n)%/%n*20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc@xTsMwEAbg3U9RGVWkKBJp6EgGCiyVEBJhj67uOTWNz8h2KvnpwyWwZGCIdNL9y/2fzg/RWGx6iqZrTAwNdF3jruirQfekonGUpVzntAm9zfRj4rS@X9NdWQzJ9ZU8gMUghfYG6RQqlcn9F3hCmctXo868PlzgWw5PJ5AbQVUpbla7QvwDZ1yb/9UxJsTE1BH8ZcbUEa@j8nn7fOZb4LgHIvQcauVinKwHtsqFVvgGO6OOwKUriW0bxq2dY6NzHu1kbNnYFguR97ZNM@QA6sK1L4g8HN744TQ@5Y6/SrHsleEH)

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##lc@xTsMwEAbg3U9RGVWkKBJp6EgGCiyVEBJhj67uOTWNz8h2KvnpwyWwZGCIdNL9y/2fzg/RWGx6iqZrTAwNdF3jruirQfekonGUpVzntAm9zfRj4rS@X9NdWQzJ9ZU8gMUghfYG6RQqlcn9F3hCmctXo868PlzgWw5PJ5AbQVUpbla7QvwDZ1yb/9UxJsTE1BH8ZcbUEa@j8nn7fOZb4LgHIvQcauVinKwHtsqFVvgGO6OOwKUriW0bxq2dY6NzHu1kbNnYFguR97ZNM@QA6sK1L4g8HN744TQ@5Y6/SrHsleEH "R – Try It Online")

Comment: Very nice!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 23 bytes

```perl6
(*Xgt*).sum div*×20+20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/RSsMwFIbv9xSHc6Gujq6t4o1UWHU3QxGsiDC9OOtOs7qkGUkdFHwPH8gH65JWZ0jg58/5v/zZsZFXnWrhpIS0OwteRROMQ/upYF3tg5/vJDpPou56ZKmFEr7UNAzGN2/pNJy/zO6h1AZkVbPtABek2OIElph9kKnZSZxXxQbBLaeftHVY787W5Mz3CST@ClJ3LqMRYN6Q2faEvOE9o089n95uSEryuYzqmo1XeaGbBh3h4khIPMHuSPnYEldkcHiXhbB/HUqtf12pDStPiI@EOPKIRyHaAbGgYov98B2z24N@cB37Acz0avhGHP2XOAA)

Gets the number of other people before us in the queue, integer divides that by `n`, adds 1 and multiplies by 20.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṭṢi³N:⁵×-20
```

A full program accepting arguments `name`, `friends`, and `n` which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzrUPdy7KPLTZz@pR49bD03WNDP7//6/klZibWqz0P1rJKSuxKC9VSUdByTUzOQNEB@UXF5fmgliOKYlKsf@NAA)**

#### How?

```
ṭṢi³N:⁵×-20 - Main Link: name, friends
ṭ           - tack (friends to name)
 Ṣ          - sort
   ³        - 1st program arg = name
  i         - (1-based) index of (name in sort result)
    N       - negate
      ⁵     - 3rd program arg = n
     :      - integer division
        -20 - minus twenty
       ×    - multiply
            - implicit print
```

Comment: Do you mean `n` rather than `ten` in the explanation (talking about superscript 5)?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I did, thanks. Force of habbit!

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <strike>46</strike> <strike>40</strike> <strike>39</strike> <strike>38</strike> 31 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,c{~b.count{|i|i<a}/c*-20}
```

-5 -1 byte from petStorm.

-1 byte from Rahul Verma.

-7 bytes from Dingus.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc5Na8MwDAbge3@F0aUw0vVj166wdLsUxmDZLewgu8pHm8TFdgYh7f56JscdMcK8CD1IppXdkD0Pix1GMlL9r3xUum1cfy2v5RZvS/Ww2Kxuw0VkqYAD1mQhEinEJzQNcYS3UhUg@HH@1Na2te@@HJGb35HY8D8LOnFozqNOHP0QePE13xdYVehNjE1DxqdEaeeA9dOk7QVrT1KQaCDsozy3/7szre/dShuqvV5P@iPPu6APqM4wzr0ScYX8zqeNAxBrGS5fr1jPhj8)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 83 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,c{(b.push(a).sort.each_slice(c).map{|x|x.include?(a)}.find_index(true)+1)*20}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7fT4MwEAfw9/0V5F4ExWbMZzWiviwxJuIbMctRjh8OKGmLYdn2t@MVNGva5pvLfXKnh@wwFffT7QOGWSiPfib6wVQ@BsIobQWhrHamqSX5MhAt9sfTeBpF3clmyOmR@86iqLt8x49G3@qBgpsouN6sz1PvFakHW2zJQOilEH@j7ogjvNayAo8P5w9lzNC66lOOXPwKvQ3/q0UnFvV@1omlHwInPq@eK2wadCbGriPtUiKVtcD67qJNj60jKWSoYZlHZWn@ZxdK/VUbpal1Orro97I8LHqLcg9z3wsR3yW/8WpzA8QqWzaP1qxX0y8)

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##Rc5RT8IwEAfwdz5Fcy8CTtzwzSiEoS8kxoT5tvhwrbcxWdelHSYE@OzzumpoLs0/l/vlzh7ksS@e@7sFRjJSp7GcaWxP5@o8rp5wskwe48vMHfS9uk0m03l86VtR5AI2qMlBJHJIv9E2xBFeK7UDwY/z1jhWvrv6Qm5@RmLO/yjorEO7H3TW0Q@BFx836x3WNXqTYtOQ9SlTpuuA9cNVuxa1JzlItBD2UVm6/92FMX/d2ljSXidX/V6Wx6A3qPYwzL0QcYX8xqcNA5AaGS5PYtaj/hc "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##Rc5Na8MwDAbge3@F0WVfWZt0t7EPlq2Xwigsu4UdZE9Js8RxsJNBafvbUzneqBHmRehBsoPcjcXjePuEkYzU/lLONXb7Q3WoHlA8J/fxce4GvVA3ydX1Mj6OnShyAWvU5CASOaQ/aFviCKtKbUHw4/xhHCvffflGbn5FYsn/LOisR1tPOuvpl8CLz4vXLTYNepNi25L1KVOm74H13Vm7DrUnOUi0EPZRWbr/3YUxf93GWNJeJ2e9Kctd0GtUNUxzb0RcIb/zadMApEaGy5OY9Ww8AQ)

Comment: [Squeeze out a byte](https://tio.run/##Rc5Nb8IwDAbgO78i8mWwlY/CdZu0AhekCWndreLgZG7paBuUhEl8/fbOaUBEVvTK8iPbHOSxzd/a4TtGMlLnvhxZqki586W8lK94HdnyRGP1Eg@ep5Nruxd5JmCFNVmIRAbJL5qGOMKyVFsQ/Dh/aWsPte9@/CA3N5GY8t8LOnVodp1OHf0RePH9NN9iVaE3CTYNGZ9SpZ0D1rOHtnusPclAooGwj4rC3nfnWt@6lTZUex0/9LoojkGvUO2gm1sQcYX8yad1A5BoGS6PJ6x77T8 "Ruby – Try It Online") by using filter.

Comment: [Another byte](https://tio.run/##Rc5Na8MwDAbge3@F0aXQZV2aXbdB0/VSKINlt7CD7Clpmg8H2y10bX97JscrNcK8CD1I5iBPQ/E6PL5hJCN1lnNLDSl3vlSX6gWvc1v90pOaJfFDEl@HXhS5gA22ZCESOaR7NB1xhHWldiD4cf7U1h5a313@IDe/I5HwPwk6c2jqUWeOjgRefE1XO2wa9CbFriPjU6a0c8D6@a5tj60nOUg0EPZRWdrb7kLr/26jDbVeL@76oyxPQW9Q1TDOvRNxhbzl08YBSLUMly9i1pPhDw) squeezed off!

Comment: You must be kidding me

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##Rc7BisIwEAbgu08R5iKsXbXuVRfsuhdBBLu3sodJnNaubSNJKoj67HXSrBiG8DPMx4xp5aXLF937J0YyUtfZdPwmx0q3jbveyls5x/tEjeJ7dxJ5JmCNNVmIRAbJH5qGOMJ3qQ4g@HHeaWvb2neXe@TmbyRm/A@CTh2aY69TR2cCL36GXwesKvQmwaYh41OqtHPA@uOl7QlrTzKQaCDso6Kwz9251v/dShuqvY5felsUl6DXqI7Qz62IuELe8Gn9ACRahsvjKetB9wA)

Comment: Make that [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##Rc5Na8MwDAbge3@F0aUw0vVj166wdLsUxmDZLewgu8pHm8TFdgYh7f56JscdMcK8CD1IppXdkD0Pix1GMlL9r3xUum1cfy2v5RZvS/Ww2Kxuw0VkqYAD1mQhEinEJzQNcYS3UhUg@HH@1Na2te@@HJGb35HY8D8LOnFozqNOHP0QePE13xdYVehNjE1DxqdEaeeA9dOk7QVrT1KQaCDsozy3/7szre/dShuqvV5P@iPPu6APqM4wzr0ScYX8zqeNAxBrGS5fr1jPhj8) :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>53</s> <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:~sorted([a]+b).index(a)//c*-20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc49T8MwEAbgnV8R3dKYBvq1VerQAEslhETY0g5n5/LRxnZkG0QX/nqwk7aq5eHVq3t0151drdWqLzf7vkXJC4ww4YlY/1ltHBVxjocpZ8@NKug3Rjabicen5bzvTKNcXMawQ0kWkiiH9IhGkY/w1ogaIv98/tTWfsvQbgv05SGJlow93Hzm0JwGnzn6IQjma/JSY9tiUCkqRSakTGjnwPvVvbcdyoBy4Ghg3ElVZa/7S60vbasNyeAX9/6jqs6j36E4wTD5SuT/mN/9ecMApJqP9y/mjPX/)

Adds your name to list of friends, sorts the list and calculates the answer from the index of your name in the sorted list.

*Special thanks to Jonathan Allan for -1 byte*

Comment: `lambda a,b,c:~sorted([a]+b).index(a)//c*-20` saves one :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```rust
|s,l:&[&str],n|20+l.iter().filter(|x|*x<s).count()/n*20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddBBT4MwFAfw@z5F1wNpJ0FATyoHiV6WGBPxZnZ4sAfDlda0xcyInx0LSLKY0DTNv6/NL33VrbF9KUkDtWScfK8IEWhJSRLSd8YXN96bZ6ze@bKLwwsR1BY140FZiyF0p25zujM8KFQrLeOXchOHPXHjdjWsYAxqu2b7vFqzknl0Cw0a6hOn0vQdtMRhQx/r4kDd/SG/KGPaZizf78FVdz6JCefuOEncch3yBTyzoI9/eGbxE@kIvhYHEAJGMQUpUY8xK5S11OFXZ3i8iJsPaEbP4Tno@bVYVWbOpVJzFEpjM@DRGR6Fi/pzVX3N@haKI52YB0Q3pzaeXHPTHZqqfPqXKPz39J/@Fw)

*Special thanks to user and madlaina*

This is my first ever code golf so I hope I have the format correct!

Comment: Try using [Try it online](https://tio.run/##ddBBT4MwFAfw@z5F1wNpJ0FAT04OEr0sMSbizezwYA@GK61pi5kRPzsWkGQxrmmaf1@bX/qqW2P7UpIGask4@VoQItCSkiSk74wvbrxXz1i99WUXhysmgtqiZjwoazGE7titjreGB4VqpWX8Ul5EfN0TN8AY1HbJdnm1ZCXz6AYaNNQnTqTpG2iJw4Y@1MWeuvtDflbGtM1YvtuBq259EhPO3XGSuOU65OvFv3hmQR9@8cziB9IRfCn2IASMYgpSoh5jVihrqcOvTvD4LG7eoRk9h@eg59diVZk5l0rNUSiNzYBHJ3gUntWfqupz1jdQHOjE3CO6ObXx6Jqb7tBU5dO/ROGfp3/3Pw). It counts your bytes and even generates Markdown for you

Comment: Ah nice, although I put the semi-colon in the footer

Comment: You can expand the parentheses and save a byte: `20+l.iter().filter(|x|*x<s).count()/n*20`

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/),  <s>48</s>  45 bytes

```
method(s,a,n,((a select(<s)size+1)/n)ceil*20)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9PSwMxEMXvfophLiYasFtvUg@ueimI4Hr0Mk1nd2PzpyRR0C@/Jl210CGHN495P15MmHq4uYW3yXEew1YkRcorIQgSW9ZZrJJM5psvG3nlpWZjL5YLOfUC1@Q4oQJrUhbYvlP0XFZ8NHpEKFP0S0jpw1X3bkvFlAqWIGEfjc/Wn/UCsMsUd/@YLvMnY42@nt@PZC3VcEvec6yq0yFnLJhrOOGkPbkanDkbijhX4GFIf3X6EH5dGyK7ymlOOc/D8HXkrEnv8JB4YC5v1k@l8uEI27CZv9UsjpzpBw)

### Explanation

```
method(s,a,n,((      // Take 3 arguments.
    a select(<s)     // Take all items in the array a that is smaller than s
       size + 1)     // Take the size of that, and add 1
    /n)              // Divide it by n
ceil * 20)           // Take the ceiling of that, multiply by 20
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
20*1+(<.@%~0 i.~/:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczLCoJQFIXhuU@xCeJkF9OaaUHZZSBFkD3A3trWNPXEORY08dVNg/XPPlbeDiyRwNoFAVOwwe2aWbC7no7twh47k9HK2gwbGzKrmbtma7YLgAREQCVr4YGfk6oYD1n8wKvU@l3i9k7G8o/CmtSzQ2HNH8bb7kFFQehTVbHCMJZ1bTh/qF9UCvAgIoWcphoTKbGQikvDsXtwSdNvDwKKn7hn7obn7vyLvox@)

#### How it works

```
 20*1+(<.@%~0 i.~/:)
                  /:  ascending indices for sorting
             0 i.~    find your name
           %~         divided by interviewers
        <.@           and floored
  20*1+               +1 then *20
```

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##HczLCoJAFMbxvU9xCGK6mtpuKii7LKIItAc4JzvedWLGgja9ulnw/Xc/vrzt2SKGlQQBE3BAdk1t2AanQ@s5I3c8WNrr/mcmM9uRw3bYegAxiCNVbMQC/Jx0zbjPohQDZcyzws2drPkfhQ3pokNhwy/G6zalsiT0qa5ZYxipprHcPzQPqgQs4EYaOUkMxkphqTRXluv8wCVJ3j9wpKjAHXM3PHfnb/TV7Qs)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) , 16 bytes

```
R`©¸«{®QsôOƶ20*O
```

Explentation:

```
R`©¸«{®QsôOƶ20*O
R                    Reverse input
 `                   Push input to stack seperatly
  ©                  Store your name in register C
   ¸                 Listify
    «                Merge lists (add your name to the list of names)
     {               Sort
      ®              Push your name
       Q             For each element; is it equal to your name?
        s            Swap (n on top)
         ô           Split list of names into n chunks
          O          Sum each element
           ƶ         Lift a, multiplying each element by its index
            20*      Multiply by 20
               O     Sum for the result
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/KOHQykM7Dq2uPrQusPjwFv9j24wMtPz//49WUPJKzE0tVtJRiFZyykosyksFMpVcM5MzlBQUFIDMoPzi4tJckKBjSiJQLFZHwQhIAgA)

Comment: [`ª{¹kI÷>20*` **10 bytes**](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0KrqQzuzPQ9vtzMy0Pr/3ysxN7WYK1rJKSuxKC9VSUfJNTM5A0gF5RcXl@YCGY4piUqxXEYA) (and [here a test suite for all test cases at once](https://tio.run/##JY3NCoJQEIVfRWYZd6G2T5LaCBFkQSBCo01q/tzwmiDte4DeohZt29ub9CI2F2GYOcN854xUGGU0tJ0Dxu/@MMDpDrv@OfSvW//O99/PzDYngxiCIAD3jHVFIGCZxSmPjVTqWrKYHxFCAR6WpEDYoTCY9htqNbyNUywKZOViVVHNwo9l02iH32Cdg5iOjgj1kZKEQ@AkJfdC1lRqUl2QP1kj6GHMLlgQcbFYcUqnH8hIs@sk4c0yw/AP)).

Comment: Nice! should I add it to the answer?

Comment: Your choice. I could also add it as a different answer if you prefer. Either is fine by me.

Comment: I think it would be okay to post as different answer since the approach is different :)

Comment: [Done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209843/52210). :)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
20×⌈⎕÷⍨⊃⍋⍋⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoJADEXXzinczcoE8QSibkiMiXiBgsOgDgyB0YS1C4kKO@IVvIEH4CZzEWxJmvbn9/UXcjU7VqC0HGz9iAfX6T/2Xdu263@2@drn3TYvqrYjYJjEjPuQipJPuXeGIhMoNqcowbHXZXlNUSyPwJnLiA0MFBe0AiNuhB5WCSgFdA1ZJgpaRdoYzhYjX@ZACSHQRkhJf2KtsStdiJSz@YjtpKzQ8yGi8LUQWCi2@Ix8T4dIOn8)

Full program that takes the names and the value of n from stdin.

#### How it works

```apl
20×⌈⎕÷⍨⊃⍋⍋⎕
          ⎕  ⍝ Take first input (names)
        ⍋⍋   ⍝ Rank the names alphabetically; A E C B D → 1 5 3 2 4
       ⊃     ⍝ Extract the first number
   ⌈⎕÷⍨      ⍝ Take second input (n), divide above by n, and ceiling it
20×          ⍝ Multiply 20
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>29</s> 23 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Rahul Verma*

```scala
y=>_.count(_<y)/_*20+20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pdDfT4MwEAfwd/6KS59aJcrQp0WWbNEHFxcT8c2Y5daVjg1aQrtFYvzbsfyYG6@OELheuE@Or@GYYa1XW8EtLDBVIL6sUGsD06KAb@@AGcgxxLZMlYRoAvQlNfajO3/68Kwsa9ruDVFdRZPlDdd7ZenyoWK3y6swuA6Dei0SSGh1dHzAMQwdNe4pkLRiFF2HeR4aI0pLE0rmmAtD/HaKktkWSyXckTylfEPAXa5@08bs86Y7XaNrMh9C94QogvuAnWGxxXL3h8VWHARpgHe@wSzDRpihUqJsqphra4mz7norHFimwLwZ7qwVlqRbRkhpjoslWvfdTJcib7BRj42CgfYqZXXS5sh3pJ17FMLdXb1wy7cfkZledb85Ck6reYWL1GbqwtTYufP/wAbMBVkNnAtScvn81L8)

Accepts `(y)(a, n)`. `y` is a `String` representing your name, `a` is a `List[String]` with your <s>competitors'</s> "friends'" names, and `n` is an `Int` representing the number of interviewers. The function is pretty straightfoward - it just finds how many friends will go before you (plus 1 because you're going to go too), divides that by `n` (rounding up), and multiplies by 20 to get the total time.

Comment: The output is empty in TIO... (I don't know about Scala, btw)

Comment: @RahulVerma Those are just a bunch of assertions. [Here's](https://tio.run/##pdBRS8MwEAfw932KI0@JFu2mT2IHG/rgcAjWNxG5ZdeuW5uUJBsW8bPXZJ3OvroS2svR/Lj8rcQSW71Yk3Qwx0IBfThSSwuTuobPwQ5LyG6Ap84UKo/gsbDutdu8RfCgnIBkHL6QtAC8iTBSIhlzvJB6qxx/v23EuRKX6mwUt2gtGcczzmZYkWUdx9l0jUaR37L7Qq4Y@MfXz9rabRW6kyX6pohg5N@QJHAdi8ERSx2azS@WOtoRC8CLXGFZYhCmqBSZUKVSO8e8dXWwRj3L1liFw521QMO6YSjP7c9gmdaHbqkNVQEbHrBh3NOe8rw5ajOUG7Y/d0fkV1fP/fD7n9hUL7prDuPjaIPaZ@1KdWJq4q/z/8B6zAlZ9ZwTUvL5fLXf) one with print statements

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##pdBRT4MwEAfw932KS59AiTL0yciSEX1wcTER34wxR3cwNmhJ2y0S42fHdkwnr0IauF7oL9e/5lhhJ7MNcQNLLAXQhyGx0jBvGvic7LGC/Aa81KhSFAE8ltq89pu3AB6E8SGeuS/EHYDXBhgIP57hBZc7Ybz329a/FGdReB6FHWpNyni5xxZYk2a95rFkg0qQ3bL7kq8Z2MfWz1LrXe268xXaph9AZN8Qx3Ad@pMTlhpU218sNbQn5oAXvsaqQickKAQpV6VcGsOsdXW0ooGlG6zd4d7KULF@GCoK/TNYLuWxW0lFtcOmR2waDrSnomhP2gL5lh3O3RHZ1ddLO/zhJ5bIrL/mNDyNNmls1KYSI1Pz/zr/D2zAjMhq4IxIyebz1X0D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
Ｉ×²⁰⊕÷ΣＥη‹ιθζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYy9CsIwFEZf5ZLpBiJIVyf/hhYFUbficEku9EqTapJ28OVj@g2Hwxk@O1C0E42l3KKEjEdKGZ/iOWGzNdAGG9lzyOywDfkkizjGx@zxSh8cDFw4JRQDX621gZ9etyulB9VRPVEGenV4UwxcVZ3FDgoAqt6nlGa/xr2j2l4GmsqyWcY/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
        η       Second input (array of friends)
       Ｅ        Map over array
          ι     Current friend
         ‹      Alphabetically precedes
           θ    First input (your name)
      Σ         Take the sum
     ÷          Integer divided by
            ζ   Number of simultaneous interviews
    ⊕           Incremented
 ×              Multiplied by
  ²⁰            Literal `20`
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 68 bytes

```c
l;f(p,n)char**p;{for(l=0;p[++l]&&strcmp(*p,p[l])>0;);n=20+--l/n*20;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVBbS8MwFH7frzgEHOmaYTaHD8YJDn0RRHC@1SJZl3ZxaRqSqsjob59JVi97EhJy@G7n5BTjqij2e8VKbIhOig23o5Fhu7KxWM0pM1maqnw4dK0taoNHhphM5ckVZQnT8ylNx2N1qkdTyrp9zaXGCewGMQU0r4XLZnl2nsPcowA7dBcwRAAtXrnVIlS3stggAPDlY@PcWx3A6zVHAaIdib5ly@02EMtWvAsUxE@@i1I8hnGthY100bQt@vU5w@uoXnHbNxFV5fqybJq@Uo0V9R/fQ1V9Rt8dL7ZxEnQjhD8RvPfDHOhFs/qZs2MDqVvwV9h3KT6EDb8PX4cpOSMTMqHQaz64bL@5GSVT6rnwBN5vHnAM8jRl/rmEGYM0lUlcYqBeQoCnS3xYsszJcV@ZJyxoS8Cxl/S95gdb4nEAY72@xMhw5y7gZA34ZJ08a7@CKCLQ22KMUE4cuUou1T@ubtDtvwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 54 bytes

```java
(m,l,q)->l.filter(x->x.compareTo(m)<0).count()/q*20+20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVJNj9owFLznVzwhreRsjQv0VrZIi9pDV9uutOFW9fAITjD4I9gOC6347fSRD1pUKU7s8cy8if02uMfhZrU9K1M5H2FDa1FHpcX9NPkPC9FLNJetXGMI8A2Vhd8JgLJR@gJzCQtlpG8wAO1sCZEAlkWvaG44ZI3FQwvMQPOLFnY12qjiMZ2S8JTQq6qXWuUQIkb67J1agaFqndOPn4C@DGlXqC0am/cnODPDNd@lw5kWhdKUjB2Gs4PInanQy4VjJn0YpbSubWTp@939ZPRuMjpPG689egg5Wtt4WfkGWbti2TFEaYSyact8WystgXVkscbwXR7is7KSpX2y1k8TRmaP3uMxCAzPKsSrzl5FIlRaRTbgMEi7Gq3eXNQXE1HKyEY3e/3REeMr3UJJjnvUtXwp2FXRTIL6RTWG41vrwitpV6H3D/WyCTfmcCvqNd0huDqKim4iFmxwFzg0Y/WRxp2l/Eby3plfE/L2hkTTEf8wurZi6V9qn/HUtMPp/IRGktN8g96S8IvK1xxeXQg1tdTjCjlMkiyi314aTO6JssjXqDVtzJtTJjx3MXL4kIQKSbREwmRZkmvhHP2t85LgcfJSlpT0CXPy@iwlPZz63G8JnLslMUZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ª{¹kI÷>20*
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0KrqQzuzPQ9vtzMy0Pr/3ysxN7WYK1rJKSuxKC9VSUfJNTM5A0gF5RcXl@YCGY4piUqxXEYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JY3NCoJQEIVfRWYZd6G2T5LaCBFkQSBCo01q/tzwmiDte4DeohZt29ub9CI2F2GYOcN854xUGGU0tJ0Dxu/@MMDpDrv@OfSvW//O99/PzDYngxiCIAD3jHVFIGCZxSmPjVTqWrKYHxFCAR6WpEDYoTCY9htqNbyNUywKZOViVVHNwo9l02iH32Cdg5iOjgj1kZKEQ@AkJfdC1lRqUl2QP1kj6GHMLlgQcbFYcUqnH8hIs@sk4c0yw/AP).

**Explanation:**

```python
ª           # Add the first (implicit) input-string to the (implicit) input-list
 {          # Sort the list alphabetically
  ¹k        # Get the 0-based index of the first input in the sorted list
    I÷      # Integer-divide it by the input-integer
      >     # Increase it by 1
       20*  # And multiply it by 20
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 35 bytes

```
20⌈{#}~Union~#2~Position~#/#3⌉&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc7RasIwFIDh@z1FSMGLUdDVyzGo4m6EoazuAY7ZaRttkpFEQUp6PcGn9EW6nDAMgfNf5CNHgW9RgZcCxpq9jcXsfvvtszB8aWn0kBXD1jjpU0@z@f12nYxbK7Uvn2tWliXrn1g8PV@DQsfzWMsDWI0x@bsULc1P49xJUS2@gYecFSH/Z5UHe0ys8nhOaida6DqgXILWaKkqYbwnOn9Q9wMqyT2kJ9g0tACvjaHRGYuKxMtDbJrmksQaBH3KV4jxUn3ENS7pS7NPaBbC6/gH) Pure function. Takes the three arguments in order and returns `{{x}}`, where `x` is the desired number of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
èsl=j/üI*
```

Inputs in the order and format `"myName" numberOfInterviewers "an","Array","Of","Friends"`.
Assumes the names only contains letters. Will delete and fix it if they can contain digits as well.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##FY7PCsIwDIfvPkXJUQT/nT049KAggvMFspp1bu0qbRX2Rj6Etz1Y/Q1C8pF8JHGcGuNtnfP4jXbXLsffaZ4zndlJJLVRVLQceqEFHZ@6Qbn5GN8OsH8wzahMHDpSWwWSz@TddcPWMqjgvpcAKLVPCXJ8sSO1VlTx1BZjIkrtPbL1QRycqzEDnJXCD7rD4CCCAFxwaZjW@or@)

**Explanation:**

```python
è         # Push all inputs as single string array
          #  i.e. "Oggy" 10 "Jack","DeeDee","Marky","Bob"
          #   → ['Oggy','10','Jack','DeeDee','Marky','Bob']
 s        # Sort this array alphabetically
          #  → ['10','Bob','DeeDee','Jack','Marky','Oggy']
  l       # Push the first input as string
          #  → ['10','Bob','DeeDee','Jack','Marky','Oggy'] and 'Oggy'
   =      # Get its 0-based index in the array
          #  → 5
    j     # Push the second input as float
          #  → 5 and 10.0
     /    # Divide the index by this float
          #  → 0.5
      ü   # Ceil it to an integer
          #  → 1
       I* # Multiply it by 20
          #  → 20
          # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```